# Changing commas into colon after third consecutive commas

Tags: jquery

I'm asking a question based on my previous question [JQuery-csv not parsing all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038618/jquery-csv-not-parsing-all-values) ,this question will be a workaround on my problem which was solved but still needed a bit tweaking where the overflowed cell won't show up, but I can't figure out where or how to start with it.

My csv file looks like this: test.csv

```
header1, header2, header3, header4
value1, value2, value3, value4
value1, value2, value3, value4.1,value4.2,value4.3
value1, value2, value3, value4
```

Im parsing the csv using `csv.parsers.splitLines` , but this time I would like to check line by line that after the 3rd comma `,` I'll get all the remaining strings and replace the comma with some other separator like a colon `:`.
ex:

```
value1, value2, value3, value4.1,value4.2,value4.3 --> value1, value2, value3, value4.1-value4.2-value4.3
```

at the moment I still don't know where to start in this issue a good nudge in this would be awesome.
cheers!!

JSFiddle for my ideal output:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/690880/

Comment: split the string by comma (str.split(',')) and make sure you trim any whitespace of each of those elements after splitting. Then, iterate through the split array - if the element is index < 3 then output to your string a simple comma, if it is >= 3 then output to your string the value + ' --> '.

Comment: Precisely what output do you want to obtain from that CSV input?

Comment: @ChrisCousins that's precisely what i needed, i'll give a go what u have said but now im thinking how would i join the split string.

Comment: @DavidThomas i have added a jsfiddle on my ideal output and stuff, hope it clarify what im missing

Comment: @ChrisCousins im using the method csv.toArrays from `jquery-csv` this is convenient in making a 2 dimensional array from the data but i cant wrap my mind around how to iterate and at the same time add those overflowed data into one cell. http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/691107/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine, here we go:

```
            var separator = ",",
                agregator = "-";
            function generateTable(lines) {
                if (typeof(lines) === 'undefined' || lines.length == 0) {
                    return '';
                }
                var header = lines[0].split(separator);
                var html = '';
                var rows = [];
                // mapping
                for (var row in lines) {
                    if(row == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var cols = lines[row].split(separator),
                        values = {};
                    for (var col in cols) {
                        var item = header[col] ? header[col] : header[header.length-1];
                        if(values[item]) {
                            values[item].push(cols[col]);
                        } else {
                            values[item] = [cols[col]];
                        }
                    }
                    rows.push(values);
                }
                // printing
                for(var row in rows) {
                    html += '<tr>\r\n';
                    for(var item in rows[row]) {
                        html += '<td>' + item + ':' + rows[row][item].join(agregator) + '</td>\r\n';
                    }
                    html += '</tr>\r\n';
                }
                return html;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#result').html(generateTable($.csv.parsers.splitLines(response)));
                }
            });
```

As I said on the previous question, to achieve what you want you must map those values first, then print those information. Please notice I changed a litle bit our code with new variables `separator` and `agregator` just to make it easy to change.
Also that overflow solution just wraps the "lost cases" to the last header, if you know what I mean.
As you got the [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52040174/4265572) I will just talk about the changes.

## Mapping

```
                for (var row in lines) {
                    if(row == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var cols = lines[row].split(separator),
                        values = {};
                    for (var col in cols) {
                        var item = header[col] ? header[col] : header[header.length-1];
                        if(values[item]) {
                            values[item].push(cols[col]);
                        } else {
                            values[item] = [cols[col]];
                        }
                    }
                    rows.push(values);
                }
```

Instead of populating the html variable, here I'll populate `rows` with simple objects. I decided to use a simple syntax: `{headerName: [headerValues]}`. So each header with the same name will be on the same array. Easy, right? One loop to rows, one loop to cols and we're done.

## Printing

```
                for(var row in rows) {
                    html += '<tr>\r\n';
                    for(var item in rows[row]) {
                        html += '<td>' + item + ':' + rows[row][item].join(agregator) + '</td>\r\n';
                    }
                    html += '</tr>\r\n';
                }
```

Printing is more easy because the hardest part has gone. You just need to loop rows and cols again, just making a syntax conversion: `{headerName:[headerValues]}` to `<td>headerName: [headerValues].join(agregator)</td>`.

Comment: great as always! i have implemented it and im getting a single row for every row, but i would need to keep each cell in the row and not merge all cell, i would like to only merge the cell of those overflowed data. like this http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/690880/

Comment: updated question, i have clarified it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52054827/add-overflow-table-cell-in-a-cell-with-a-header , or if possible from your answer bro to make there own table cell.

Comment: solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52057909/4265572 hehe if I woudl change it here would be complicated to understand